# Pandas DataFrame Table Index Change

Tags: python, sql, pandas, database, dataframe

Here is what I do, I take a SQL table and I read it with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

Being ***"query"***, the tables I want to take from the data base and ***"conn"*** the connection to the data base. The query I do, just in case you need to know is basically a SELECT where I join multiple tables, and I group them by the quantity and the sum. Something like this:

```
SELECT p.quantity, sum(s.count)
FROM data_base.stock s
JOIN blah blah
JOIN blah blah
JOIN blah blah
WHERE blah blah
GROUP BY p.quantity
```

That gives me a table like this:
Total Available Beers:

```
**quantity**        **sum**
220             3223
620             5654
315             3455
```

I want the table to not have the default names, I want to stablish them, I found this next line of code could work:

```
df = df.rename(
 columns={'quantity': 'Presentation (mL)', 'sum':'Available (Unities)'},
 index={'220': '220mL Bottle', '315':'315mL Bottle', '620':'620mL Bottle'}
               )
```

And, here is the problem, the resulting table is shown like this, the index do not change:

```
**Presentation(mL)**        **Availale (Unities)**
220                         3223
620                         5654
315                         3455
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your quantity column is an index rather than a column?

Comment: If "Presentation(mL)" is index and you want to rename the index of dataframe, df.index.name = 'Presentation (mL)'.
If you want to rename the columns, df.rename(columns={"quantity": "resentation (mL)", "sum": "Availale (Unities)"})

Comment: @EmiOB I am quite sure it is, this is the documentation or the examples I am basing in: [Pandas Dataframe Rename](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pandas-dataframe-rename/)

Comment: @Alex I do change the columns, and it works, as you say. But the indexes I want to change are "220", "315" and "620", and as I am doing it does not work.

Comment: willyro93, "quantity" is the column? if then, please try with df.set_index('Presentation(mL)')

Comment: @Alex No, it does not work. Maybe I am misunderstanding what indexes and columns are, I am lost here

Comment: Thanks for your time, I found how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it, as what I wanted to change was the "220", "315" and "620" values, all I needed to do was:

```
 df["Presentation(mL)"].replace(
                                 {220:"220mL Bottle",
                                  315:"315mL Bottle",
                                  620:"620mL Bottle"},
                                  inplace=True
                               )
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try aliasing in the query itself?

Like this.

```
SELECT p.quantity as Presentation(mL), 
sum(s.count) as Available(Unities)
FROM data_base.stock s
JOIN blah blah
JOIN blah blah
JOIN blah blah
WHERE blah blah
GROUP BY p.quantity
```

This will assign desired field name to your dataframe. The result anyway has proper indexing that starts from 0 to n.